# Android crash in Oreo: RuntimeException : ColorStateList has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getStateCoorList

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

App is getting crashed in Oreo devices due to some `Resourcs.getColorStateList()`
Please check the below screenshot.

[image: Crash log]

Comment: StackTraces is giving you meaningful hint, use other methods as directed above.

Comment: @Zoombie It is showing the changes in library-level not in the app.

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing a similar exception from Android support library. This happens when I run the app in emulator (API 27).

ColorStateList android:color/text_color_primary has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getColorStateList(int, Theme) or Context.getColorStateList(int).
             java.lang.RuntimeException